# SQL Server Partition table filter by column data & partitions having rows greater one

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, partitioning

I have a SQL Server partitioned table where I am fetching data which has row count > 1, but I have a scenario where I have IsActive column and want to pull active partitions which has row count > 1 and IsActive = true.

```
SELECT      
    C.partition_number
FROM          
    sys.partition_functions A
INNER JOIN    
    sys.partition_range_values B ON (B.function_id = A.function_id
                                     AND A.name = 'pf_Employee')
INNER JOIN     
    sys.partitions C ON (C.partition_number = B.boundary_id
                         AND OBJECT_NAME(C.object_id) = 'Employee'
                         AND C.index_id = 0)
WHERE        
    C.rows > 0;
```

How to add `IsActive` flag along with `C.rows > 0` in the above query?

Comment: I am not sure I understand this correctly, you need one more condition in your query? `WHERE isActive = true`?

Comment: yes, IsActive is a column in Employee table and I want to add IsActive = true in the where clause.

Comment: `WHERE C.rows > 0 AND C.IsActive = True` ?

Comment: C is sys.partitions not the table itself, we cannot access IsActive like that which is a column in table itself

Comment: Can you please provide some sample input and output that you would like to see? I am sorry I am quite unclear at what the goal is.

Comment: @BorisJovanovic there is a sql server paritioned table partitioned by employee Id's range, 0 - 1600 one partition and 1600 - 3200 another partition and so on,and each row has a column data IsActive which represent if employee is active or not.. I am trying to query this partitioned table for my batch purposes where I have rows in a partition and IsActive = 1, i hope i explained it well.

Comment: Okay I think I understand, the thing is, you are not accessing that table in any way within your query, so it might be tricky to actually filter on it. I assume you are passing the partition number to somewhere else, is there a way for you to filter it at that part?

Comment: Ya I could do it, I could filter within in each partition to find IsActive = true, but I want to avoid that scenario as there are lot of partitions which has IsActive = false so unnecessarily we are adding overhead on the batch process to check again if that partitions has active rows or not. So, I was trying to get the partitions that has IsActive = true so that I don't have to check back again for each partition.

Comment: Makes sense. Maybe filter it before this step, you are this query just to access the table, maybe try "altering" the table before accessing it? When I say altering I just mean, query it with the condition and then access that query with this partitions.

Comment: If you see my query above it is querying to find c.Rows > 0, so i will be getting partitions that have data, now i need to query the partitions again where isActive = true to check for at least one record in that partitions else ignore that partition for further batch processing, so it's two step process which I am looking to avoid :)

Comment: @Larnu we are using SQL Server 2016, I know there wont be IsActive in those System View, IsActive is actually a table column to determine employee is active or not. Some partition there wont be any employees and they will be empty and some they will have employees but all of them may be IsActive = false, so C.Rows > 0 would filter partitions that doesn't have rows, now how can I filter making use of table column to check IsActive = true to pull only partitoin where we have rows and IsActive = true records in one query,  looking for an extension to above query like if we can achieve it.

Comment: *"we are using SQL Server 2016"* Then why did you tag [tag:sql-server-2008] and [tag:sql-server-2012]? And is the column is in a different table, why aren't you referencing that table in your query? Sample data and expected results will help us help you.

Comment: @Larnu to bring more attention i tagged them as well and I cannot remove them now as edit option is not available, Why aren't you referencing that table in your query ? --> that is the question right on how to join on the table in above query, please answer if you know on how to join and get the results, if you see above comments i mentioned above sample data on how the data in table looks like thanks

Comment: @Larnu can you answer the question if you know how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
 SELECT      
    DISTINCT C.partition_number
FROM          
    sys.partition_functions A
INNER JOIN    
    sys.partition_range_values B ON (B.function_id = A.function_id
                                     AND A.name = 'pf_Employee')
INNER JOIN     
    sys.partitions C ON (C.partition_number = B.boundary_id
                         AND OBJECT_NAME(C.object_id) = 'Employee'
                         AND C.index_id = 0)
INNER JOIN DBO.Employee E ON 
$PARTITION.pf_Employee(EmployeeId) = c.partition_number 
WHERE C.rows > 0 AND E.IsActive = 1
```

Comment: *"I think someone down voted my question, don't understand why the question was down voted without providing solution."* Downvotes have nothing to do with providing a solution. When you hover over the downvote option, it says "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" which means, *normally* that is the reason why. Someone that downvotes (or upvotes) does not need to comment or provuide a solution. They are anonymous by intention.

Comment: @Larnu I understand that, i was thinking why on earth someone would downvote the question anyway thanks for your time and effort to explain things

Answer (score 2):

If you want a solution that doesn't require a scan of the table, you can track the per-partition statistics in an indexed view.

EG

```
create or alter view vActiveEmps
with schemabinding 
as
select $partition.pf_employee(id) partition_id,  
       sum(isnull(Active,0)) ActiveEmployees, 
       count_big(*) TotalEmployees
from dbo.employee
group by $partition.pf_employee(id)
go
create unique clustered index pk_vActiveEmps on vActiveEmps(partition_id)
go
select partition_id
from vActiveEmps 
where ActiveEmployees > 0
```